# Magento 2 scandipwa theme install in our local server we are getting the node-sass,node-gyp and python2 errors?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4, pwa, pwa-theme, scandipwa

we have tried to install existing magento scandipwa theme.we are getting node-sass, node-gyp and phython2 error.please check the attached screenshot

**User Guide** : https://docs.scandipwa.com/getting-started-1/magento-integration

we have follows steps as per user guide:
first we have create existing magento root create src/localmodule directory.

**step** 1 : **mkdir src/localmodule**

**step** 2 : **cd src/localmodule**

--> after go to src/localmodule this directory and run the below command. we are getting the below error as per screenshot.

**Command :** **npx create-scandipwa-app my-app**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7406T.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPSyx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WVyj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoZam.png

Comment: It is showing error because you have to install node 14 version and also install python 2

Comment: @ZahidHussainMagento i have installed latest node 18.16.0 and python 2.7 version. one more thing no needed to install node or python 2 version?

Comment: your python is OK but you need to downgrade node to 14 version b/ca node-sass is not compatible with 18 version. I was facing same issue then I downgrade node-js to 14 version and started working it.

Comment: @ZahidHussainMagento yes now it is working after node js version 14 downgrade.now i am getting the below error while linking theme in magento
https://i.imgur.com/1Slewwd.png

Comment: Try composer update in magento root path

Comment: @ZahidHussainMagento upgrade issue solved, when ever i deploy command run that time the below error throwing.
https://i.imgur.com/ELee7wl.png